# HTML 5 video autoplay stop after playing a second

Tags: ajax, html5-video

I've run into a problem with HTML5 Video.
I'm loading the source of the video dynamically via Ajax. When it's loaded from the server, it should start automatically as I've set the autoplay and loop attributes.

The problem is that it only plays for a second and then immediately stops, any help on this would be awesome.

Thank you all.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a working copy of this or any additional information? What browser(s)?

Comment: @TimHayes Sorry that It is not online yet. I was trying at localhost using chrome. I've noticed that it played onyl a second and suddenly it stopped strangely. here is my code for that.

`<video id="product_video" class="demoVideo" src="http://192.168.1.144:8080/Sample/videos/002.mp4" type="application/mp4"></video>`

Comment: Thanks all. now my problem has been solved. after getting data with Ajax I did put some extra event listener (loaded data and pause) and then play it. I've got this solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179645/html5-video-to-play-after-ajax-page-load).